# Actualizar una columna en función de otras 3 postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

necesito actualizar una columna en base a la siguiente condición
[image: tabla con la que trabajo]

Necesito actualizar la columna `nombre_generadora` con el campo `mvietiquet` cuando el campo de `mvingenera` sea igual a `mvinprinci`, entonces actualizar todos los campos que tengan ese numero en `mvinprinci` en `nombre_generadora`.

Por ejemplo, un valor de `mvingenera` es '040000S0' y en `mvinprinci` hay 20 campos que tienen ese valor, tendría que darle a esos 20 campos en `nombre_generadora` el nombre de `mvieqtiquet` que corresponde a '`040000S0`'.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si ya lo has conseguido, sería de la siguiente forma:

```
update nombre_tabla set nombre_generadora = mvietiquet
where mvinprinci = mvingenera;
```

Si no añades una condición se actualizan todos los datos.